# Spark: I need to save the prediction from below Scala code into a file instead of showing it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark: I need to save the prediction from below Scala code into a file instead of showing it?? how can I do it??
val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

```
< val rawDataTest = sc.textFile("/home/hduser1/Pictures/LogTextTest.txt")
 val header1 = rawDataTest.first()
 val rawDataTest1 = rawDataTest.filter(line => line != header1)
 val records1 = rawDataTest1.map(line => line.split(","))
 records1.first()

case class StumbleUpon1(id: String, text: String)
val data1 = records1.map{ r1 =>
    val trimmed1 = r1.map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))
    //val label1 = trimmed(r1.size - 1).toInt
    val features = trimmed1.slice(0, r1.size)
    assert(features.size == 2)
    StumbleUpon1(features(0), features(1))
}


 data1.first()
 val Test = data1.toDF("id", "text")
 Test.show(15)

 val predictions = model.transform(Test)
predictions.show(5) >
```